# "list assignment index out of range" with numpy.histogram

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to use Numpy with Python to compute a histogram with automatic bin size. My reading of the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) says that I should be able to pass `bins="auto"`, but when I do so, I get an error:

```
import sys
import numpy as np

print(sys.version)
# 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21)
# [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)]

print(np.version.version)
# 1.8.0rc1

print(np.histogram([1, 2, 3, 4], bins='auto'))
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "/Users/phrogz/Code/histopy/histo.py", line 11, in <module>
#     print(np.histogram([1, 2, 3, 4], bins='auto'))
#   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 183, in histogram
#     if (np.diff(bins) < 0).any():
#   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 991, in diff
#     slice1[axis] = slice(1, None)
# IndexError: list assignment index out of range#
#
# Process finished with exit code 1
```

I get the same result with any string parameter for `bins`, while it works as expected if I supply any integer for the parameter. What am I doing wrong, and how do I get automatic bin size calculation?

Comment: Since you get a traceback, you can debug this. Looks like the autocalculated `bins` happens to be out fo range but I've no idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was PyCharm using Python 2.7 (as seen by `sys.version`, which I hadn't noticed until I added it to the details for the question). When I switched PyCharm to use 3.5, it works as expected.

```
import sys
import numpy as np

print(sys.version)
# 3.5.2 (default, Oct 11 2016, 05:05:28)
# [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)]

print(np.version.version)
# 1.11.2

print(np.histogram([1, 2, 3, 4], bins='auto'))
# (array([1, 1, 2]), array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.]))
```

Comment: That doesn't really show the root cause for the error. Was the `numpy` used from the 3.5 installation or something?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev No idea; I'm quite new to Python (and PyCharm, and pip3). I've edited the answer to show that I get a different version of numpy when I switch the interpreter; perhaps it was an older numpy?

Comment: According to https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.8.0/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html#numpy.histogram , it appears that in `1.8.0`, `histogram` has `bins=10` by default and does not accept `"auto"`. I would expect it to raise an exception then but apparently, it doesn't. Maybe it's because it's `rc`. If you run under debugger, you should probably see the `10` at the faulty line. Alternatively, `"auto"` may be being misinterpreted as a "sequence of scalars".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the version on numpy you are using. The auto feature was introduced in numpy version 1.11.0. 
Maybe the version labeling is confusing as 1.8.0 < 1.11.0 because the 11 has to be read as elven not one point one.